# Interrupt handling with 8051 C using Keil uVision

Tags: c, 8051, keil

I've been doing a project about home automation in which I have to use timer interrupts with 8051 microcontroller. I've constructed the following code, however I couldn't manage to get interrupt working. It seems that the program does not go into timer ISR at all. I use a buton to simulate PIR input, therefore lampControl is triggered, no worries there. I use  as a library.

Any ideas or help will be greately appreciated:

```
void timer0_isr(void) interrupt 1  //Timer 0 Interrupt
{
        TH0 = 0xDC;
        TL0 = 0x00;
        TR0 = 1;
        if (++lamp_interrupt_count == 6000)
        {
            sendCharacterShowAsHex(0x8F); 

            lamp_interrupt_count = 0;                

            TR0 = 0;
        }   
}



void main()
{  
    unsigned char chr;

    IE = 0x93;    
    while(1)
    {
        serialInput();
        if (getPIRInput() == 0x00)
        {
            lampControl(0x80);
        }

        ....
                ....
                ....
}




void lampControl(unsigned char serial_data_in)
{
    if (serial_data_in == 0x80)
    {
        sendCharacterShowAsHex(0x80);

        //enable interrupts
        IE = 0x93;  

        device_interrupt = 2; //Lamp

        TMOD = 0x21; // Timer0 Gate=0, Mode 1, 16bit timer
        TH0 = 0xDC;
        TL0 = 0x00;
        TR0 = 1; 

    }
    else if(serial_data_in == 0x8F)
    {
        sendCharacterShowAsHex(0x8F);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the timer and interrupts before you can use them.
In main() you need at least the following configuration bits set in order to be able to turn
the timer on with "TR0 = 1;" :

Set those bits first thing in main() and this should do the trick:

```
TMOD = 0x01;        // 16-bit no auto reload
TH0 = 0xDC;         //Set high and low bits to count 0xFFFF - 0xDC00 = 0x23FF counts
TL0 = 0x00;
ET0 = 1;            // Enable timer0 interrupt
EA = 1;             // Enable all interrupts
//TR0 = 1;          //Enable Timer0 immediately
```

The rest of your code should run fine.

Note: you could change your interrupt function definition to:
"void timer0_isr(void) interrupt 1 using 1" to force it to use register bank 1 for the interrupt function operation.

Comment: CKCON is not valid in 8051, what should I use instead?

Comment: what processor are you using? ex. AT89C51CC03

Comment: AT89C51 in Proteus,  <reg51> in Keil

Comment: CKCON = 0x01 is very critical unless you want to run the timer in 2x mode, so the code should run just fine without it.

Comment: What else would be the reason? I should generate a 1 minute delay using interrupt. I used IE register to modify EA and ET0

Comment: Found that in your code you forgot to set the TH0 and TL0 values. Changed my answer to a working code I just tested; the code part should go in main, no other configuration is needed. If you need to turn the timer to start counting immediately, uncomment the TR0 = 1; part.

Comment: I did set TH0 and TL0. The problem worked itself. It seems that EA should be configured after TMOD. Weird. Thanks for the help.